# Rails gem paypal-express founds not added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm using the gem paypal-express https://github.com/nov/paypal-express/ and it works fine, now  it is the time to go live so i changed the config/paypal.yml in this way

```
development: &sandbox # change to your own
  username: seller_1330103613***
  password: *******
  signature: *******
  sandbox: true

test:
  <<: *sandbox

production: &production
  username: *******
  password: *******
  signature: *******
  sendbox: false
```

of course, i configured the API access by requesting API credentials to create my own API username and password.
Payment flow from my site, to paypal and back again to my site after the user has payed works fine but I can see the money on my paypal account, no found has been added to my account.
Into the log i can see just this when the user get back from paypal

```
Started GET "/payments/success?credit_pack_id=6&user_id=951&token=EC-4P010757XB594990R&PayerID=LS9LDEH84VBAY" for 79.41.57.162 at 2013-06-20 23:07:31 +0200
```

Where else can i check in order to fix it?
Is there any not-well configured permission in paypal or anything else?
thank you

Comment: Have you tried logging into paypal and seeing the status of this transaction there?

Comment: i have not the transaction in the buyer section...this think is get my crazy...

Comment: Are you sure you're not logging into the sandbox paypal account?

Comment: pretty sure, i tried to change the production api access (username, psw, signature) with some fake value and I can complete the paypal transaction, so, i assume, i'm using those credentials